# Combinatorial Operations

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, functions

Given are the real line and the two unique marked points $0$ and $1$. We can perform as many times as we want the following operation: we take two already marked points $a$ and $b$ and mark the reflection of $a$ over $b$. Let $f(n)$ be the minimum number of operations needed to mark on the real line the number $n$ (which is the number at a distance $\left| n\right|$ from $0$ and it is on the right of $0$ if $n>0$ and on the left of $0$ if $n<0$). For example, $f(0)=f(1)=0$ and $f(-1)=f(2)=1$. Find $f(n)$.

What I thought: check f(5). 5 can be marked by reflecting -2 over 1. in this case f(5)=2, not 3, as your function suggests.

Comment: Well, for powers of 2, the answer is $\log_2(n)$

Comment: you can’t get to -2 in just one reflection, f(-2)= 2, f(5) really is 3

Comment: When I reflect $-2$ over $1$, I get $4$, not $5$. "as your function suggests" What do you mean by *your function*?

Comment: @GerryMyerson A possible solution to the problem, perhaps

Comment: It might help us to know what contest this comes from.

Comment: @GerryMyerson This problem is from the Brazilian math Olympiad 2019

Comment: The problem is so easy that you just have to test one by one until you realize the pattern... And then you see that @Robo300 almost answered it.

Comment: @WhatsUp But an Olympics would require a more creative explanation, no?

Comment: I was trying to tell you that I got the answer and I suggested you work more on it.

Comment: OK, it's Problema 2 at https://www.obm.org.br/content/uploads/2019/11/Prova_Nivel_3_OBM_2019.pdf

Comment: @GerryMyerson They had posted problem 3 here too

Comment: "Here"? Where, please.

Comment: With regards to the final sentence, 1) Reflecting -2 over 1 gives 4, not 5. 2) Note that -2 cannot be reached in 1 step. 3) I calculate that $f(5) = 3$

Comment: @EsposaDoYoongi I rewrote the constructive approach and it's now much better and immediate. Sleep is important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With each step, we can at most double the maximum distance between any 2 marked points. Hence, the numbers in the sets $S^n = \{ 2^{n-1} + 1, 2^{n-1} + 2 + \ldots + 2^n\}$ and the negative counterparts $ T^n = \{- 2^{n-1}, -2^{n-1} + 1, \ldots, -2^{n} - 1 \}$ will need at least $n$ steps.

It remains to show that $n$ steps is enough. This can be done via 2 different approaches below.

The case for $T^n$ can be done similarly (by flipping the number line around) so we will just focus on $S^n$.
For a given $s\in S^{n}$, let $s_1, \ldots, s_{n} = s$ be the sequence of marks that we take to reach $s$. If needed, $s_0 = 1$ which we're given for free.

---

Constructive approach.

For $s \in S^n$, let
 $f(s) = \begin{cases} \frac{ s+1}{2} & s \text{ odd} \\ \frac{s}{2} & s \text{ even} \end{cases} $.
Construct the sequence $ s, f(s), f^2(s), \ldots f^n(s) = 2$.
(Note: Why is $f^n(s) = 2$?)

Follow the rule: To get mark $s_i$,
If $f^{n+1-i} (s)$ is odd, flip 1 about $s_{i-1}$.
If $f^{n+1-1} (s)$ is even, flip 0 about $s_{i-1}$.

The reason why this works is:

- Flipping 1 about $s_{i-1}$ gives $s_{i} = 2s_{i-1}-1$
- Flipping 0 about $s_{i-}$ gives $s_{i} = 2s_{i-1}$

This is the inverse map of the function $f$, hence we obtain the marks $s_i$ as the reverse of the constructed sequence, and in particular $s_n = s$ as desired.

To see this in action, consider say $s=22$, we get the sequence $ 22 \rightarrow   11 \rightarrow 6 \rightarrow 3 \rightarrow 2$.
$s_1:$ Since 2 is even, flip 0 about 1 to get 2.
$s_2:$ Since 3 is odd, flip 1 about 2 to get 3.
$s_3:$ Since 6 is even, flip 0 about 3 to get 6.
$s_4:$ Since 11 is odd, flip 1 about 6 to get 11.
$s_5:$ Since 22 is even, flip 0 about 11 to get 22.

---

Existence approach. (I came up with this first, because the induction was very natural to consider. However, the previous approach is better, hence it's listed above.)
The resulting sequence of marks is different from the above, in part for odd $n$ $s_1=-1$ instead of $2$.

For $s \in S^{n+1}$ odd:
We will take $s_1 = -1$, obtained by flipping $1$ to $-1$.
Then, consider the map of the real line $ \rho: x \rightarrow \frac{x+1}{2}$. $\rho (1) = 1, \rho (-1 ) = 0, \rho (s) = \frac{ s + 1 } { 2 } \in S^n$.
Hence, there is some series of marks $s^* _1, s^*_2, \ldots s^*_n = \frac{ s + 1 } { 2 } $.
Hence, we can take  $s_{i+1} = \rho^{-1} (s^*_i)$, to reach $s_{n+1} = \rho^{-1} (s^*_n) = s$.

Similarly, for $s \in S^{n+1} $ even:
We will take $s_1 = 2$ obtained by flipping $0$ to $2$.
Then, consider the map of the real line $ \rho: x \rightarrow \frac{x}{2}$. $\rho (2) = 1, \rho (0 ) = 1, \rho (s) = \frac{ s} { 2 } \in S^n$.
Hence, there is some series of marks $s^* _1, s^*_2, \ldots s^*_n = \frac{ s } { 2 } $.
Hence, we can take  $s_{i+1} = \rho^{-1} (s^*_i)$, to reach $s_{n+1} = \rho^{-1} (s^*_n) = s$.

Comment: Nice solution! Thank you very much!